# Compiling python files using py_compile in command line

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I am using the following command to compile a specific python script:

`python3 -m py_compile abc.py`

However I want this compiled file to reside in a different directory. I haven't been able to find anything over the internet regarding this. Is this even possible? So, I am trying something like:

`python3 -m py_compile abc.py /Users/documents/abc.pyc`

ofcourse the above command gives an error saying it can't find the file or directory `/Users/documents/abc.pyc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible to specify named arguments with `-m` option. If `-m` is necessary, you can create a wrapper that runs `py_compile` and pass arguments with sys.argv.

$ cat compile_it.py

```
import sys
import py_compile
# cfile` is named argument for destination filename
py_compile.compile(sys.argv[1],  cfile=sys.argv[2])
```

And use it with:
`python -m compile_it abc.py /Users/documents/abc.pyc`

Or without `-m`:
`python compile_it.py abc.py /Users/documents/abc.pyc`

Comment: What does -m option signify here?

Comment: `-m - Search sys.path for the named module and execute its contents as the __main__ module`. See https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

In this specific example using -m is not necessary at all.